# Ordenação com jquery.dataTables.js e jquery.dataTables.columnFilter bug

Tags: jquery, jquery-datatables

[image: Imagem][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEw4K.jpg)Olá, amigos estou tentando colocar os filtro na primeira linha do head da tabela, quase funcionou senão fosse pelo fato da ordenação, como mostro na imagem. As células de ordenação tem que ficar na primeira do header que não tem os text box. Estou utilizando os Plugins jquery.dataTables.js e para os filtros jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js

Alguém pode ajudar.

Código abaixo

```
<table id="example" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:150px">Company name</th>

            <th style="width:350px">Date Created</th>
            <th style="width:250px">Date Updated</th>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Company name</th>

            <th>Date Created</th>
            <th>Date Updated</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Emkay Entertainments</td>

            <td>28/05/2011</td>
            <td>25/08/2011 00:00:00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>The Empire</td>


            <td>16/06/2011</td>
            <td>10/07/2011 00:00:00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Asadul Ltd</td>

            <td>13/07/2011</td>
            <td>12/09/2011 00:00:00</td>

        </tr>![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][2]
 </table>



 $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').dataTable(
                )
                .columnFilter({
                    sPlaceHolder: "head:before",
                    aoColumns: [
                        { type: "text" },
                        { type: "text" },
                        { type: "text" },
                    ]
                });
        });
```

[2]:

Comment: chegou a ver no console para ver se retorna algum tipo de erro ?

Comment: Fala mestre entendi que você quis colocar a chamada ... tudo bem mas não ajuda muito não seria melhor colocar o retorno caso erro no console do browser ?

Comment: aproveita e da uma olhada no thead que tem duas linhas duplicando ... talvez isto possa gerar seu problema

Comment: tem que ter mesmo manow as linhas duplicadas

Comment: Já resolvi galera.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi colocando esta propriedade  **"bSortCellsTop": true** na função DataTable.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#tbConvenios').dataTable({
            "bSortCellsTop": true
            })
      .columnFilter({
          sPlaceHolder: "head:before",
          aoColumns: [{ type: "text" },
                      { type: "text" },
                      { type: "text" },
                      { type: "text" }
          ]
      });
    });
```